# Alert me when a certain app/process isn't running

Tags: notifications, macos

Is it easily possible to have some sort of cron job or something run on my Mac that alerts / notifies me when a certain program isn't running?

I use an app last.fm, and since it doesn't run in my dock I don't notice that the process might not be running any more.

Comment: so you use the Last.fm Scrobbler for Mac  app ?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/q/16064957

Comment: @Buscar웃 yup! will check that out - that seems similar, except that the answer i need is in the question, and not vice versa :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a simple applescript and creating a cronjob to run it every 10 minutes.

When Last.fm is not running, this launches it.  when it is running, it does nothing.

AppleScript:

```
tell application "Last.fm" to run
```

Cronjob

```
*/10 * * * * osascript /Users/Jacob/Documents/AppleScripts/LastFMRunning.scpt
```